# How do I send a variable to php and go to a div within one link?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Bottom line: I'm looking for advice on how to fix my code so that when I click a link, it opens a popup (currently does) and moves over a variable for php.

I have a script that produces a popup in the same window while greying everything else on. I want to do this, but allow the link to eventually select which php file fills the pop up div. Please help. The pop up works great, but the variable to the div, not so much.

```
<html>

  <!-- Include jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Include jQuery Popup Overlay -->
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay/1.7.13/jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      // Initialize the plugin
      $('#fadeandscale').popup({
        pagecontainer: '.container',
        transition: 'all 0.3s'
      });

      $.fn.popup.defaults.pagecontainer = '.container'

    });


  </script>

  <style>
    #fadeandscale {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
           -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
            -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
                transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    .popup_visible #fadeandscale {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
           -moz-transform: scale(1);
            -ms-transform: scale(1);
                transform: scale(1);
    }
    .well {
      max-width: 500px;
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-top:40px;
      background-color: white;
      border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
         -moz-border-radius: 5px;
              border-radius: 5px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
         -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
              box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);

      font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
      font-family: 'Glegoo', serif;
      color:#990000;
      font-weight:lighter;
    }
    #close {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>




<div class="container">
  <!-- Add an optional button to open the popup -->

  <a class="initialism fadeandscale_open btn btn-success" href="#fadeandscale?link=Link1">Link 1</a>
  <a class="initialism fadeandscale_open btn btn-success" href="#fadeandscale?link=Link2">Link 2</a>

  <!-- Add content to the popup -->
  <div id="fadeandscale" class="well">



    <?php 
      $linkname = $_POST["link"];
      echo $linkname;
      echo "Link name: $linkname"; ?>

    <!-- Add an optional button to close the popup -->
    <div id="close">
      <a class="fadeandscale_close">Close</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</html>
```

For reference, here's the current page in test: http://wolfpackhome.myqnapcloud.com/jquerypopuptest

Comment: What DIV are you looking to focus on?

Comment: What is view? I can't any dom element with name property set as view in your code

Comment: @Drew Lean When I click the link, the "fadeandscale" DIV opens. That's where I want to eventually put php code to include a php file given variables (i.e. include 'optionsdata.php?symbol=$symbol&expiry=$expiry').

Comment: @Pushpendra my mistake. I tried to clean up the file for stackoverflow. "view" is what I now called "link" it's a dummy element I was hoping to grab with $_POST or $_GET, but it doesn't work. I'll update the main code to match what I explained here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fadeandscale').popup({
                    pagecontainer: '.container',
                    transition: 'all 0.3s', onopen: function() {
                    }
            });
            $('a[name="link"]').click(function() {
                $('#linkName').html("Link name:" + this.id);            
                $.ajax({
                    url: "modal.php?id=" + this.id,
                    success: function(resdata) {
                        if (resdata != null ) {
                             $('#fadeandscale').html(resdata);
                             $('#fadeandscale').popup('show');
                        }
                    }
                });
                $.fn.popup.defaults.pagecontainer = '.container'
            });
        });

// Html code   



<div class="container">
  <!-- Add an optional button to open the popup -->
  <a class="initialism fadeandscale_open btn btn-success" name="link" id="Link1" href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a class="initialism fadeandscale_open btn btn-success" name="link" id="Link2" href="#">Link 2</a>
  <!-- Add content to the popup -->
  <div id="fadeandscale" class="well">
  </div>
</div>

----- modal.php

    <?php
    $linkname = $_GET["id"];
    ?>
    <span id="linkName"><?php echo $linkname; ?></span>
    <div id="close">
          <a class="fadeandscale_close">Close</a>
    </div>

I have made below changes

 1. Changed href as "href=#" 
 2. Added id and name for the anchor element
 3. Added click handler for the anchor element and triggered the ajax call.
 4. Moved the popup code to Modal.php and called through ajax.

It looks not possible to pass the value with help of popup, so i made these changes.
```

Comment: wow, nice! This is further along than I had gotten definitely. Is it possible to pass the id (or linkName) variable to a php variable?

Comment: My goal is to eventually have the pop up only be the php code: <?php include 'optionsdata.php?symbol=$symbol&expiry=$expiry'; ?> or something like that... probably with a lot more variables

Comment: Why u want to set the value here in php variable?

Comment: I want to pop up a dynamic page that grabs the variables based on the link and provides more detailed information. I can build a php file to format the info I want, I just need to figure out how to get it there without changing pages.

Comment: AWESOME!! This looks like it's going to work! I'll test it a little more tomorrow, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: If it works! Please mark as answered. So that it will be helpful for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your popup with `AJAX`, by this you can easily send variables in URL via `GET`,

Comment: This should rather be a comment instead of answer.

Comment: Is there an example using AJAX to send a variable and direct at a div? Or really my end goal, click on a link on a table for amplifying information. I want that information to by dynamic (based on variables versus a page for each link on the table)

Comment: problem with this is that I have to define what each link does. I want to dynamically create the link and content. I'll likely end up with 30-40 links I'd want to open

Comment: So whats the problem, just send a `type` parameter also with `id` via `GET`, then collect your data from DB related to id n type, and modal will be open according to id and type,

Comment: Or create separate page for each modal type, and just send an id,